# Number of subsets when each pair of distinct elements is contained in exactly one subset

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

> Let $E$ be a set of cardinality $n$. Suppose $M_1, M_2, .. , M_m$ are
>    distinct proper subsets of $E$ such that for each pair of distinct elements $x_1, x_2\in E$, there is exactly one $M_i\supseteq\{x_1,x_2\}$. Prove that $m \ge n$.

It's obvious $n$ has to be greater or equal to $3$. Also, for $n=3$, it's easy to prove it, but I have no idea how to extend it. I think a proof using induction by $n$ is possible.

Comment: Those $x_1,x_2$ should be different, shouldn't they?

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes, different

Comment: You surely mean $n \leq 3$?

Comment: @aduh There is no subset so that $M_x = \{1,3\}$

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk I said $n \ge 3$

Comment: Tried to concoct an acceptable title.

Comment: @Did It's better now, thanks

Comment: WHAT DO YOU DO WITH $x_i,x_j\in E$ FOR $i$ FIXED AND $j\ne i$ IF YOU WANT TO FOLLOW THE CONDITION OF THE PROBLEM? You said "The fact that there must be an element common to (almost) all sets is simply not true". IF YOU WERE RIGHT THEN YOU CAN NOT OBEY THE CONDITION OF THE PROBLEM. YOUR COMMENT IS OBTUSE.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Hi, I posted an answer to your problem. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Is there any problem with my answer? Please let me know if there is anything that I can improve exposition of the answer. Or, if you think it is not correct, let me know so that I can fix them.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for general case**

Let $E=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Define column vectors $v_j=(v_{ij})^T$ with $v_{ij}= \mathbf{1}_{M_j}(i)$ which gives $1$ if $i\in M_j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $M=(v_{ij})$ is an $n\times m$ matrix consisting of $0$, $1$ entries. Our goal is to prove that $\mathrm{rank}(M)=n$. We will show this by proving that the rows of $M$ are linearly independent. Then the columns $v_j$ form an spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and it will follow that $m\geq n$.

According to the assumptions, for each $i$,  there are at least two sets $M_{j_1}$ and $M_{j_2}$ such that $i\in M_{j_1}\cap M_{j_2}$. Otherwise, the pairs $\{i,1\}$, $\ldots$, $\{i,n\}$ are all included in one set $M_k$ which gives $M_k=E$. Thus, we see that any row of $M$ contains at least two $1$'s.

Consider a $n\times n$ matrix $MM^T$. If $MM^T$ is nonsingular then the rows of $M$ are linearly independent. For the proof, let $M^T x = 0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $MM^T x = 0$. Since $MM^T$ is nonsingular, $x=0$. Write the rows of $M$ as $R_1, \ldots , R_n$. Then $MM^T = (b_{ij})$ with the dot product $b_{ij}=R_i\cdot R_j$.

Since any row has at least two $1$'s, we have $b_{ii}\geq 2$. Since any pair $\{i, j\}$ with $i \neq j$ is in exactly one $M_k$, we have $b_{ij}=1$ for $i\neq j$. Writing the determinant as a multlinear function on columns, we obtain that $$\det MM^T \geq 1+n.$$
Therefore we conclude that $MM^T$ is nonsingular, and we are done.

**Proof of the determinant inequality**

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n\times n$   matrix with $a_{ij} = 1$ for $i\neq j$, and $a_{ii}\geq 2$. Then $\det A \geq 1+n$. For the proof, let $J=(1, 1, \ldots, 1)^T$, and write the determinant as a multilinear function on columns:
$$
\begin{align}
\det A &= \det \left((a_{11}-1) e_1 + J, \ldots, (a_{nn}-1)e_n + J\right)\\
&=\det \left((a_{11}-1)e_1, \ldots, (a_{nn}-1)e_n \right) \\ &+ \sum_{j=1}^n \det \left((a_{11}-1)e_1, \ldots, J (j-\textrm{th column}), \ldots,  (a_{nn}-1)e_n \right)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n (a_{ii}-1) + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_{ii}-1)}{a_{jj}-1}\geq 1 + n.
\end{align}$$

**An Example for $n=4$**

An example of such matrix $M$ is 
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},  \ \ \ 
MM^T=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \det MM^T = 16.$$

**Possibility of $m=n$**

Note that it is possible to have $n$ distinct subsets $M_1, \ldots, M_n$ satisfying the requirements. Let $M_1=\{2,3,\ldots, n \}$, $M_2=\{1,2\}$, $M_3=\{1,3\}$, $\ldots$, $M_n = \{1, n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather long proof.

From the condition, we find that for any two sets $M_i,M_j$ then $|M_i \cap M_j|\le 1$. Let $E= \{ 1,2, \cdots , n \}$ and $a_i \; (1 \le i \le n)$ be number of sets $M_j$ so that $i \in M_j$ then $a_i \ge 2$. Thus, $$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{a_i}{2} = \sum_{1 \le i<j \le n}|M_i \cap M_j| = \binom m2-L,$$
where $L$ is number of pairs of sets $(M_i,M_j)$ so $|M_i \cap M_j|=0$.

Now, consider an arbitrary set $M_l= \{ x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_h \}$ then the total numbers of sets $M_j \; (1 \le j \le m)$ so that $|M_j \cap M_l| =1$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^h a_{x_i}-|M_l|+1$. Thus, $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^h a_{x_i}-|M_l|+1=m-l_l$, where *$l_i$ is number of sets $M_j$ so $|M_j \cap M_i|=0$*.

Thus, similarly, by considering all set $M_i= \{ y_1, \cdots , y_l \}$ so that $1 \in M_i$ we find $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^l a_{y_i}-|M_i|+1 = m-l_i$. We add all of these to get 
$$a_{1}^2+\sum_{i=2}^na_i - \sum_{1 \in M_i}|M_i|+a_1 = ma_1-\sum_{1 \in M_i} l_i, \qquad (1)$$ 
which is deduced from the fact that $|M_a \cap M_b| \le 1$ so in all $M_i \; (1 \in M_i)$ then if $j \in M_h \; (1 \in M_h, j \ne 1)$ then $j \not\in M_k \; (1 \in M_k, k \ne h)$. This also follows that $ \displaystyle \sum_{j \in M_i}|M_i|=a_j+n-1.$ Thus, $(1)$ is equivalent to $$a_1^2+\sum_{i=2}^na_i-n+1 = ma_1-\sum_{1 \in M_i} l_i.$$
Hence, 
$$ \begin{array}{c} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2+(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^na_i-n^2+n = m\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\sum_{i=1}^m|M_i|l_i, 
\\ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^2-a_i)-n(n-1)+\sum_{i=1}^m|M_i|l_i = (m-n)\sum_{i=1}^na_i. 
\\ \displaystyle (m-n)(m+n-1)-2L+\sum_{i=1}^m|M_i|l_i = (m-n)\sum_{i=1}^na_i, 
\\ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m|M_i|l_i-2L = (m-n) \left( \sum_{i=1}^na_i-m-n+1 \right). \end{array}$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^ml_i=2L$ and $|M_i| \ge 2$ so $LHS \ge 2L \ge 0$. Hence, if $m<n$ then $\sum_{i=1}^na_i \le m+n-1$. But we also have $a_i \ge 2$ so $\displaystyle 2n \le \sum_{i=1}^na_i \le m+n-1$ implying $m \ge n+1$, a contradiction.

Thus, $m \ge n$.

Answer (score -2):

Take $E = \{ x_1, x_2\}$. 
There exist a set $M_{1,2}$ such that $x_1, x_2 \in M_{1,2}$.

But then $M_{1,2} = E$. This is a direct contradiction to the theorem.

Thus this doesn't work for $n<3$.

Comment: Either something else is meant by the question or I'm getting downvoted for no reason. Anyhow, some feedback would be nice.

Comment: The OP has written $n \geq 3$ two times.

Comment: I read "It's obvious for $n >3$". Goddamnit.