# Complete linear hypergraph on $n$ points

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

A complete linear hypergraph is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ such that
if $e_1, e_2\in E$ then $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$.

Let $n\geq 3$. Can we pick $E\subseteq {\cal P}(\{1,\ldots, n\})$ such that

1. $(\{1,\ldots, n\}, E)$ is a complete linear hypergraph, and
2. $|E| = n+1$

?

Comment: We can simply put $e_1=e_2=\dots=e_{n+1}=\{1\}$. If all $e_i$’s are distinct then the question becomes harder. We already had [such a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569161/s-k-subsets-of-1-2-cdots-n-s-i-cap-s-j-1-prove-that-m-leq-n) which they have closed as off-topic. Nevertheless, in its comments I showed that $|E|\le n+1$.

Comment: Also you may be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969536/number-of-subsets-when-each-pair-of-distinct-elements-is-contained-in-exactly-on) recent question.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I guess the notation $|E|=n+1$ means that $E$ has $n+1$ ***distinct*** elements? And I guess the condition "if $e_1,e_2\in E$ then $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$" was supposed to read "if $e_1,e_2\in E$ and $e_1\ne e_2$ then $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$"?

Comment: @bof Oh, yes, you are right because in Wikipedia's definition $E$ is a set, not an indexed family..

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=3$.  If $|e|>1$ for all $e\in E$, then since $|E|=4$, we have $E=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$---but $|\{1,2,3\}\cap\{1,2\}|\ne1$.

If $e,f\in E$ and $e\ne f$ and $|e|=1=|f|$, then $|e\cap f|=0\ne1$.

Hence there is a unique $e\in E$ such that $|e|=1$. WLOG $e=\{1\}$.

Then $\{2,3\}\notin E$ since $|\{1\}\cap\{2,3\}|=0\ne1$, so $E=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$---but $|\{1,2,3\}\cap\{1,2\}|\ne1$.