# If $a_{ij}=|A_i\cap A_j|$ and let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, show that $\det(A)\geq0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, determinant

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\neq0$ and $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ finite sets. For any $i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, we define $a_{ij}=|A_i\cap A_j|$ and let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\det(A)\geq0$

I took a simple example of two sets, $A_1={1,2}$, $A_2={2,3}$, $A_1\cap A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_1\cap A_2=\{2\}=A_2\cap A_1$ and $A_2\cap A_2=\{2,3\}$. Now, I tried to calculate the determinant but I am stuck and as you may notice I don't see how this problem unfolds. Any help, please?

Comment: When $n=2$, the determinant is the cardinality of the set $(A_1 \times A_2) \setminus (A_1 \cap A_2)^2$. Not sure how this can be generalized

Comment: $A$ is a sum of several matrices of the form $XX^T$ (one for each element of the union of your sets), thus positive semidefinite.

Comment: @darji grinberg Could you develop this ideea please? It sounds nice.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy could you explicitly write that case with details? I think it is an useful piece of information.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula For $n=2$: $$\det A=\det\begin{pmatrix}|A_1\cap A_1|&|A_1\cap A_2|\\|A_2\cap A_1|&|A_2\cap A_2|\end{pmatrix}=|A_1\cap A_1||A_2\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_2||A_2\cap A_1|\ .$$ As $|A_i\cap A_i|=|A_i|$ and intersecting is commutative we have $\det A=|A_1||A_2|-|A_1\cap A_2|^2$. Now, $|A\times B|=|A||B|$ and $|A\setminus B|=|A|-|B|$ and hence the interpretation *Ewan Delanoy* gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar idea was used in my previous answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969536).

We enumerate elements of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = \{b_1,\ldots, b_k\}$. Let $v_j\in\mathbb{R}^k$ with  $v_j=\mathbf{1}_{A_j}(b_i)$ which is $1$ if $b_i\in A_j$, and $0$ otherwise. Then each $v_j$ encodes the elements of $A_j$. Moreover, the $k\times n$ matrix $M$ whose $j$ th column is $v_j$, satisfies
$$
M^T M=(m_{ij})=A, \ \ m_{ij} = |A_i\cap A_j|.
$$
As darij grinberg commented, such matrix is positive semidefinite. Therefore, $\det A \geq 0$.